# Tracking context with async_hooks

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, async-hooks

I'm trying to track context through the async stack using node async_hooks. It works for most cases, however I have found this use case that I can't think how to resolve:

service.js:

```
const asyncHooks = require('async_hooks');

class Service {
  constructor() {
    this.store = {};
    this.hooks = asyncHooks.createHook({
      init: (asyncId, type, triggerAsyncId) => {
        if (this.store[triggerAsyncId]) {
          this.store[asyncId] = this.store[triggerAsyncId];
        }
      },
      destroy: (asyncId) => {
        delete this.store[asyncId];
      },
    });
    this.enable();
  }

  async run(fn) {
    this.store[asyncHooks.executionAsyncId()] = {};
    await fn();
  }

  set(key, value) {
    this.store[asyncHooks.executionAsyncId()][key] = value;
  }

  get(key) {
    const state = this.store[asyncHooks.executionAsyncId()];
    if (state) {
      return state[key];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  enable() {
    this.hooks.enable();
  }

  disable() {
    this.hooks.disable();
  }
}

module.exports = Service;
```

service.spec.js

```
const assert = require('assert');
const Service = require('./service');

describe('Service', () => {
  let service;

  afterEach(() => {
    service.disable();
  });

  it('can handle promises created out of the execution stack', async () => {
    service = new Service();

    const p = Promise.resolve();

    await service.run(async () => {
      service.set('foo');

      await p.then(() => {
        assert.strictEqual('foo', service.get());
      });
    });
  });
});
```

This test case will fail because the triggerAsyncId of the promise created when calling `next` is the executionAsyncId of the Promise.resolve() call. Which was created outside the current async stack and is a separate context. I can't see any way to marry the `next` functions async context with the context it was created in.

https://github.com/domarmstrong/async_hook_then_example

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1036 Created an issue on node help repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, which is not perfect, but does work. Wrapping the original promise with Promise.all will resolve to the correct executionAsyncId. But it does rely on the calling code being aware of the promises context.

```
const assert = require('assert');
const Service = require('./service');

describe('Service', () => {
  let service;

  afterEach(() => {
    service.disable();
  });

  it('can handle promises created out of the execution stack', async () => {
    service = new Service();

    const p = Promise.resolve();

    await service.run(async () => {
      service.set('foo');

      await Promise.all([p]).then(() => {
        assert.strictEqual('foo', service.get());
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a very similar package called [node-request-context](https://github.com/guyguyon/node-request-context) with a [blog post](https://medium.com/@guysegev/async-hooks-a-whole-new-world-of-opportunities-a1a6daf1990a) to explain it.

You haven't define any value for `foo` and you are not asking for any value when calling `service.get()` without any key. But I guess that was a minor mistake when you wrote the question.

The main issue you named was the location of `Promise.resolve`. I agree, there is no way to make it work. This is exactly the reason you've create the `run` function, so you will catch the `executionAsyncId` and track your code using it. Otherwise, you couldn't track any context.

Your code was just for testing but if you really need, you can cheat by using arrow function:

```
it('can handle promises created out of the execution stack', async () => {
  service = new Service();

  const p = () => Promise.resolve();

  await service.run(async () => {


    service.set('foo', 'bar');

    await p().then(() => {
      assert.strictEqual('bar', service.get('foo'));
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Sure, that's fine. I didn't explicitly say but my point really is that code out of your control, out of context, may do this and it completely breaks the context tracking. I've found code that does this in external libraries. And it's very hard to debug where the context is lost. So you can't trust that async hooks will always work with code out of your control.

Comment: You are right. Be aware it is experimental feature. There are a lot of discussion about it on Node GitHub project. Things may change and new API can be added

Comment: Upvote because my code was based on your package anyway ;)